# Makefile re-builds target even though its requirements have already been met

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have the following Makefile, which is supposed to fetch a bunch of soundfiles in mp3 format, based on a list of sound ids, and then convert them into .wav files. I am not so familiar with GNU make so please bear with me.

What I need as a result is a bunch of .wav files, so, I have made an "all" target, which expects these .wav files. This Makefile, when run, will download normally the .mp3 files and then convert them into .wav files. Afterwards, it will delete all .mp3 files (since I have flagged them as .INTERMEDIATE). My problem is that if I re-run this Makefile, it will try to re-download the mp3 files and re-convert them into .wav files, even though, the .wav files are already present.

I can't understand why the "all" target gets re-triggered even though it should be satisfied since all its requirements have already been met.
How can I fix that?

```
BASE_DIR := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
BASE_DIR := $(BASE_DIR:/=)
BUILD := $(BASE_DIR)/build
AUDIO := $(BUILD)/audio

SOUND_IDS_FILE := $(BASE_DIR)/sound_ids.txt
SOUND_IDS:=$(shell cat ${SOUND_IDS_FILE})

MP3_FILES:=$(patsubst %, $(AUDIO)/%.mp3, $(SOUND_IDS))

WAV_FILES:=$(patsubst %, $(AUDIO)/%.wav, $(SOUND_IDS))

.PHONY: all clean

.INTERMEDIATE: $(MP3_FILES)

# Main Rules:

all: $(WAV_FILES)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD)

# Dir Rules:

$(BUILD):
    mkdir -p $@

$(AUDIO):
    mkdir -p $@

$(WAV_FILES): $(MP3_FILES)
    @echo "Converting $< into $@ ..."
    ffmpeg -i $< -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 $@

$(MP3_FILES): $(AUDIO)
    @echo "Downloading file: $@ ..."
    sound_fetcher -i $(patsubst %.mp3,%,$(@F)) -o $(AUDIO) -format mp3
```

Comment: My guess is that it always rebuilds the mp3s because they have no real (non-intermediate) prerequisites, so it has no way of checking if they're already up to date.

Comment: Your first problem is that you cannot depend on a directory.  Make treats directories like any other target, and compares their last modified time.  Directories last modified time is updated whenever any file in that directory is added, removed, or renamed.  So when make deletes all the mp3 files, the directory timestamp is updated, and now it's newer than all the wav files it just built.  You can use order-only prerequisites if you want: `$(MP3_FILES): | $(AUDIO)`.  But I suspect as already mentioned this won't work because there's no way for make to know if the mp3 files are up to date.

Comment: @MadScientist thanks, order-only for the $(AUDIO) dir worked actually!